# How do I import Pyperclip in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have read through all the posts on the site regarding importing pyperclip but have not been able to resolve the issue.

I am working through Al Schwigert's "Automate the Boring Stuff With Python" and am on the chapter 7 exercise called "phoneAndEmail.py"

I am using Python 3.6 hosted in Jupyter Notebook and I used Anaconda to install it.

Thanks for any help

Here is my code;

```
import pyperclip

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ad44bca9d5b1> in <module>
----> 1 import pyperclip

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`pyperclip`](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip) is not part of the [anaconda distribution](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs/), so it needs to be installed.
- To install this package with [`conda`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyperclip), run one of the following (probably the first or second option) at the Anaconda prompt.

  - `conda install pyperclip`
  - `conda install -c conda-forge pyperclip`
  - `conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 pyperclip`
  - `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pyperclip`
  - `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pyperclip`
- `pip install pyperclip` for those without Anaconda